# How does a switch differentiate VLANs internally?

Tags: switch, vlan

In a simple topology of a single switch with two Access ports configured, for example fa0/1 on VLAN 10 and fa0/2 on VLAN 20, how does a switch know not to send broadcasts between these vlans if they are access ports and thus untagged. As they are unchanged Ethernet frames sent by hosts on these VLANs until they are tagged by a trunk port, how does a switch differentiate them internally?

Comment: That actually depends on the switch manufacturer and how it implemented that. There is no single answer to this question, and no standard that says it must be done one way or another. Each vendor is free to do this how it sees fit.

Answer (score 1):

The switch works by "store-and-forward": it accepts all the incoming frames, decides what to do with them, then forwards them out of the appropriate ports.

Essentially every frame will be marked with its VLANs as it is stored in the switch.  Frames arriving on access ports get tagged with the VLAN they were configured with; frames arriving on trunk ports get the VLAN of their tag, or default if they were untagged.

One of the most important things a switch does is decied to throw some frames away if they don't have anywhere they need to go.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several different implementation methods.

The most obvious approach is to split the MAC source-address table, so that each VLAN has its own table (or use the VLAN ID as extension to each MAC in a global table). Within the switch, a frame needs to keep its VLAN association (likely as an expansion of the destination MAC field) and must not be forwarded to any other VLAN. Obviously, frames received without a tag need to be associated with their VLAN immediately on ingress.

Also, the switch has to filter for broadcasts, so that they are only flooded to the VLAN members. You can do this during the process that generates the copies of the original broadcast frame or (simpler) copy a broadcast to all ports and on each port you tag and filter as required by the port's config.

The only exception to the "not forward to any other VLAN" is when an encapsulated packet is routed on a layer-3 switch. But then again, routing requires to strip the encapsulating L2 frame anyway and to reencapsulate for the destination segment, so the new VLAN ID is just another part to generate.

Answer (score 0):

The two ports are configured for different **native VLANs.**  The switch assumes or defaults the VLAN membership of untagged packets based on how that port is configured.

From [Wikipedia's IEEE802.1Q page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q):

> Portions of the network which are VLAN-aware (i.e., IEEE 802.1Q conformant) can include VLAN tags. When a frame enters the VLAN-aware portion of the network, a tag is added to represent the VLAN membership.[a] Each frame must be distinguishable as being within exactly one VLAN. A frame in the VLAN-aware portion of the network that does not contain a VLAN tag is assumed to be flowing on the **native VLAN**.

The tag is a four byte field inserted into the packet:

[image: VLAN packet]

Comment: I understand the native Vlan is the untagged Vlan on 802.1Q trunk ports, but in this scenario it is communication between two access ports only on VLANS 10 and 20 with the default Native VLAN of 1, so there must be some other way how a switch can track which traffic comes from a certain access port when tags are not involved?